# My Jframe form does not comes up when i try to make it responsive

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-8, sizing

i was trying to make my JFrame form responsive according to screen size but when try my code it doesnt comes up and if i remove the code it works fine.here is my code

```
Home frame = new Home();
    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int i = screen.width;
    int j = screen.height;
    frame.setSize(i, j);
```

please help

Comment: What values do `i` and `j` contain? (try `System.err.printf("%d / %d\n", i, j)` or use a debugger)

Comment: you say u move the code?

Comment: Dimension.width give FLOAT.Beware!!

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis He is reading the (public) fields directly which are `int` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html#height). The getters return Double though ...

Comment: Maybe your dimensions exceed the screen size when title bar and stuff get added, then you may fall into this special case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536804/setsize-doesnt-work-for-jframe

Comment: yes Andreas , y r  right.Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the answer. and it was really very simple i just need to put

```
this.setResizable(flase);
```

in my constructor.my coding was right

Answer (score 3):

To enlarge the frame to occupy the full-screen size, use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

To make the swing components responsive and adapting the frame size, use layout managers (e.g. FlowLayout):

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: i have to change the size of inner element also which will then again need to customised for which i need get this code to work i don't want alternative. i just want this code to be corrected